# Disable Driver Signing via Visual Studio Project File

Tags: visual-studio, build, msbuild, driver

Because of an exception being thrown in VS I unfortunately don't have access to the project's property dialog. I can manually edit the vcxproj file though.

So, my ask is how can I edit the vcxproj file to completely disable signing as a part of the Visual Studio build process? I don't need VS to do it, as it happens later in my build pipeline.

Comment: You can use  `<SignMode>Off</SignMode>`  in the `xxx.vcxproj` file.

Comment: Thanks! Seemed to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, my ask is how can I edit the vcxproj file to completely disable
>   signing as a part of the Visual Studio build process?

**Solution**

You can add like this in the `xxxx.vcxproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SignMode>Off</SignMode>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

**Note**: it means that you turn off the Driver Signing during the build process.

Hope it could help you.